# When will puts() fail?

Tags: c++, puts

For `puts (const char*)`, I read that, "On success, a non-negative value is returned. On error, the function returns EOF and sets the error indicator (ferror)."

I'm trying to get the function to error so I can `cout` the EOF return, but I can't seem to. If I don't initialize the `char*` to anything, or set it to NULL, it still returns a non-negative success value. What is something that would actually make this function fail? Thanks.

Side question: If you `cout <<` a function that's supposed to return EOF, will it actually print 'EOF', something else, or nothing? This is actually what I was trying to test in the first place.

Comment: One obvious possibility would be an attempt at writing to a disk that's full (and doesn't have write-back caching).

Comment: Oh I didn't think of that. Any other possibilities that I can test more easily?

Comment: You could close `stdout`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That would be UB though. The value to a pointer to a `FILE` object is indeterminate after it is closed.

Comment: @dreamlax: Yes, good point.

Comment: @Jake: In response to your side question, if you `cout << EOF << endl`; it will simply print a negative number, e.g. `-1`. Functions that return EOF typically have the return type `int`, so it simply calls  the `<<` overload for `int`.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize I could just print it that way, thanks.

Comment: write to a pipe that closes and ignore SIGPIPE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on a system that supports it (e.g., Linux), you can redirect your program's output to `/dev/full`, a device that yields an infinite stream of zero bytes on input and fails with `ENOSPC` ("No space left on device") on output.

```
./program > /dev/full
```

Of course you'll have to print any error messages to `stderr` (or `std::cerr`) or to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Linux pipes, except for "stderror" are buffered. "puts" won't give an error message (-1) using the example above.